# Getting _MailItem interface from IRDOMail

Tags: outlook, mapi, outlook-redemption

I've an Outlook plug-in. I'm using Redemption.

Specifically, I'm using IRDOMail::Move in order to move an email item from one folder to another (redemption is the only method I've found that work with all storages). I now have a need to get back a hold to the Outlook's _MailItem interface, while I only have a pointer to the redemption object. It appears Redemption works with MAPI (it is derived from), and what I need is the Outlook interface.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RDOMail.EntryID property to reopen the message as Outlook.MailItem using Namespace.GetItemFromID

Comment: Wow, Straight from the horse's mouth. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IRDOMAIL::MAPIOBJECT will give you the underlying MAPI object. Perhaps you can use that not somehow navigate to the Outlook interface.

Redemption uses MAPI yes and it also aims to be a be a full replacement for CDO 1.21